# Leaflet routing machine not giving the optimal route (by far)

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, leaflet-routing-machine

I have issues when trying to show a route on my leaflet map:

```
  L.Routing.control({
  router: L.Routing.mapbox(''),
  profile:"mapbox/driving",
  addWaypoints:false,
  waypointMode:'snap',
  routeWhileDragging: true,
  show:false,
  fitSelectedRoutes:false,
  plan:false,
  draggableWaypoints:false,
  lineOptions:{
    styles:[ {color: 'black', opacity: 0.8, weight: 6}, {color: 'red', opacity: 1, weight: 2}]
      },
  waypoints: [
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(28.6114741,77.2112497),"New Dehli"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(30.7304186,76.7789926),"Chandigarh"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(31.1047637,77.1717752),"Shimla"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(31.4493988,77.629702),"Rampur"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(31.9755409,78.5961753),"Changoa"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(32.2251899,78.0610693),"Kaza"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(32.4513357,77.860656),"Hanse"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(32.4386919,77.7497997),"losar gompa"),
  ],

}).addTo(map);
```

At the 7th waypoint (Hanse), the route is doing a U turn, adding a thousand kms to reach the 8th point that is only a few kms away.

What's going on here? I can't figure it out. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO!

This is reproducible with OSMR service instead of Mapbox:

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([32.4513357, 77.860656], 10);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.Routing.control({
  //router: L.Routing.mapbox(''),
  //profile: "mapbox/driving",
  addWaypoints: false,
  waypointMode: 'snap',
  routeWhileDragging: true,
  show: false,
  fitSelectedRoutes: false,
  plan: false,
  draggableWaypoints: false,
  lineOptions: {
    styles: [{
      color: 'black',
      opacity: 0.8,
      weight: 6
    }, {
      color: 'red',
      opacity: 1,
      weight: 2
    }]
  },
  waypoints: [
    /*L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(28.6114741, 77.2112497), "New Dehli"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(30.7304186, 76.7789926), "Chandigarh"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(31.1047637, 77.1717752), "Shimla"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(31.4493988, 77.629702), "Rampur"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(31.9755409, 78.5961753), "Changoa"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(32.2251899, 78.0610693), "Kaza"),*/
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(32.4513357, 77.860656), "Hanse"),
    L.Routing.waypoint(L.latLng(32.4386919, 77.7497997), "losar gompa"),
  ],

}).addTo(map);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@3.2.7/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@3.2.7/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

It looks like the OSM database thinks there is a "barrier" obstacle near your arrival point ("losar gompa"):

[image: Capture of OSM edit website near arrival point]

If this obstacle type cannot be crossed by car, that would explain why the router takes another (very long…) route instead.

If you think this obstacle no longer exists, please feel free to create an account on OpenStreetMap and edit the map! There is a very high chance that Mapbox router uses OSM data, therefore your modifications would be reflected some time later in Mapbox.

Comment: I don't know the region that much, actually the route I try to render can be crossed by motorcycles, that's all I know.
Can these barriers be ignored when calculating route ? I tried using walking/foot profiles but It still take the looong way.

Comment: Actually, it's a simple checkpoint as mentioned on the map.
OSRM should definitively consider these as crossable.